# Can't run rvmsudo rails s after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After updating to the latest stable build of rails, I can't seem to run rvmsudo rails s, I get `sudo: rails: command not found`. I've tried running `rvm reinstall 1.9.3` to no avail.

`rvmsudo which rails` returns: `/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rails`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rvm get head` resolved the issue for me. It looks like it was a bug as noted [here](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1329).